# Invalid Type : Schema.Fielddefinition Error

Tags: apex, soql

```
SELECT  QualifiedApiName,label FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account and QualifiedApiName  Not in ('IsDeleted')
```

When I am querying the fields from `account` object except `IsDeleted` field I am getting the below error:

> invalid type:schema.fielddefinition
>   public with sharing class SNGcRuleCreation
>   {

```
public class SNGcCriteriaWrapper{
    public SNGoCriteria__c criteria {set; get;}

    SNGcMetaDataProvider objMetaProvider = new SNGcMetaDataProvider();
    Map<String, SNGcMetadata> mapFieldMetadata = new Map<String, SNGcMetadata>();
    SNGcRuleCreation objOuterClass;
    public String orderNumber{get;set;}

    public SNGcCriteriaWrapper(SNGcRuleCreation outerClass) {
        isPickValue = false;
        isDateValue = false;
        isDateTimeValue = false;
        objOuterClass = outerClass;
        orderNumber = String.ValueOf(outerClass.objCri.Order_Number__c);            
    }

    public String dispLastRecords {set; get;}

    public void setDisplayLastRecordsHelper(){
        //For time being Current / Last Records functionality is removed.
        //setDisplayLastRecords(); 
    }

    //For time being Current / Last Records functionality is removed. 
    /*
    private void setDisplayLastRecords(){
        if(criteria.Object_Name__c == 'SNGoSurvey_Metric__c' || isChildObject('Case', criteria.Object_Name__c)){
            dispLastRecords = 'block';
        }
        else{
            dispLastRecords = 'none';
            criteria.Last_Records__c = 0;
        }
    }
    private boolean isChildObject(String parentObjectName, String childObjectName){
        String strObjectName = '';
        try{
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeParent = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(parentObjectName).getDescribe();
            List<Schema.ChildRelationship> lstChildRelationships = describeParent.getChildRelationships();
            for(Schema.ChildRelationship childRelationship : lstChildRelationships){
                strObjectName = String.valueOf(childRelationship.getChildSObject());
                System.Debug('strObjectName :' + strObjectName);
                if(strObjectName == childObjectName){
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.Debug('Exception in isChildObject() :' + ex);
            futureCreateErrorLog.createErrorRecord(ex.getMessage());
            futureCreateErrorLog.createErrorRecord(ex.getMessage());

        }
        return false;
    }
    */

    public void changeLastRecord(){
        criteria.Last_Records__c = 0;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getFields(){
        SNGcMetadata metaInfo;
        List<SelectOption> selectOpt = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        selectOpt.add(new SelectOption('','- - Select Field - -'));
        try{
            //For time being Current / Last Records functionality is removed. 
            //setDisplayLastRecords();
            System.debug('criteria.Object_Name__c++++++'+criteria.Object_Name__c);
            if(criteria.Object_Name__c != null && criteria.Object_Name__c != ''){
               checkForFieldInfo();

                List<String> lstFields = new List<String>();

                lstFields.addAll(mapFieldMetadata.keySet());
                lstFields.sort();
                system.debug('temp1...'+lstFields);
                for(String temp : lstFields){

                system.debug('temp...'+temp );

                    metaInfo = mapFieldMetadata.get(temp);

                    if(metaInfo != null){
                        if(criteria.Object_Name__c == 'SNGoSurvey_Metric__c'){
                            //if(SNGcCommonFunctions.checkObjectFieldAccess(criteria.Object_Name__c.toLowerCase(),metaInfo.fieldName)){
                                selectOpt.add(new SelectOption(metaInfo.fieldName, metaInfo.fieldLabel));

                            //}
                        }
                        else{
                            if(SNGcCommonFunctions.checkObjectFieldAccess(criteria.Object_Name__c.toLowerCase(),temp)){
                                selectOpt.add(new SelectOption(metaInfo.fieldName, metaInfo.fieldLabel));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        selectOpt.sort();

         system.debug('selectOpt...'+selectOpt);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.Debug('Exception while getting fields' + ex);
            futureCreateErrorLog.createErrorRecord(ex.getMessage());
        }       

        return selectOpt;

    }



    private void checkForFieldInfo(){
        try{
            //System.Debug(criteria.Object_Name__c + ' ' + criteria.Field_Name__c);
            //ruleobj = [SELECT Id,Name,Rule_Type__c from SNGoRule__c ];
            //System.debug('ruleobj..'+ruleobj);
            //System.Debug('ruleobj.Rule_Type__c ... ' + ruleobj.Rule_Type__c );
            if(!objOuterClass.mapObjectsWithFields.containsKey(criteria.Object_Name__c)){
                if(criteria.Object_Name__c == 'Last Survey Sent Days'|| criteria.Object_Name__c == 'Last Survey Received Days' || criteria.Object_Name__c == 'More than one closed case for a contact')
                {
                System.debug('if condition');

                    objOuterClass.mapObjectsWithFields.put(criteria.Object_Name__c, objOuterClass.getValueAsMetadata());
                }
                else{
                System.debug('else part');

                System.Debug('criteria.Object_Name__c '+ criteria.Object_Name__c);
                   // objOuterClass.mapObjectsWithFields.put(criteria.Object_Name__c, objMetaProvider.getFieldInfoMap(criteria.Object_Name__c));
        objOuterClass =  [SELECT Label,QualifiedApiName FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account' and QualifiedApiName  Not in ('IsDeleted') ];
                   System.Debug('objOuterClass... '+ objOuterClass);
                }
            }
          // mapFieldMetadata = objOuterClass.mapObjectsWithFields.get(criteria.Object_Name__c);
          mapFieldMetadata  =   objOuterClass;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.Debug('Exception in checkForFieldInfo :' + ex);
                futureCreateErrorLog.createErrorRecord(ex.getMessage());

        }            

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Missed with single quote around **Account** SObject

```
SELECT Label,QualifiedApiName FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account' and QualifiedApiName  Not in ('IsDeleted')
```

here is the working image.

[image]

Comment: I kept single quote .even though it is showing same error

Comment: Where did you try to execute this ?

Comment: in apex class.same i have executed in workbench and developer console.it is fetching the list

Comment: how do you assigned result ?

Comment: for class i have created instance.to that instance i am assigning value

Comment: No idea what you are telling about. update actual code , where your getting error and what you wanted to so ?